# Error Compiling Python 2.7.3 on CentOS5

Tags: centos, python, centos-5

I'm trying to install Python 2.7.3 on my CentOS 5.50 machine. Download, extract, configure (with `--prefix=/usr/local`) are fine. Its the `make` that throws this error:

```
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE \
      -DSVNVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C svnversion .`\"" \
      -DHGVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
      -DHGTAG="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
      -DHGBRANCH="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
      -o Modules/getbuildinfo.o ./Modules/getbuildinfo.c
gcc.orig: directory": No such file or directory
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c: In function '_Py_svnversion':
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:63: error: missing terminating " character
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:63: error: expected expression before ';' token
make-3.79.1-p7: *** [Modules/getbuildinfo.o] Error 1
```

I have been scouring the web for a few days now in an attempt to self-solve this one, but I've come up empty. One suggestion I came across was regarding "Developer Tools" being installed on the system, which I believe are properly installed, but I am not 100% sure.

If anyone has any information regarding this issue, I'd appreciate the assistance.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I've compiled and installed Python 3.3 without a hitch. The issue definitely lies with SVN. Although the packages I'm using are supported in Python 3.3, I'd still like to get 2.7.3 on there, so I'm still looking for assistance.

Comment: Not sure if this is important or not, but **svn** is version 1.7.4 on the machine.

Comment: I think it is important... I installed Python 2.7.3 successfully on another box a few months ago without issues and its running **svn** version 1.4.2.

Comment: The reason why 3.3 compiles without problems is that that source was probably never under Subversion and doesn't try to call svnversion at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409037/python-2-7-6-error-when-building-from-source-gcc-orig-directory-no-such-file/27409535#27409535

Answer (score 2):

You should `cd` to the Modules directory and look at the output of

```
svnversion .
```

on my system, with my svn version (1.6.17) it just says `exported` to stdout.
This output sets SVNVERSION as if it is with `#define` in the `C` code and actually used to define a char array. If there is garbage in there that will throw the error.

```
static const char svnversion[] = SVNVERSION;
```

I suggest you just rename the svnversion command temporarily while you compile.
Or if that doesn't work edit the function `_PY_svnversion` in `Modules/getbuildinfo.c` to:

```
const char *
_Py_svnversion(void)
{                         
    return "Unversioned directory";
}
```

It would be interesting to see what svnversion actually gives back on your system.

Comment: In the Modules directory, `svnversion .` returns `Unversioned directory`.

Comment: Also, I'm on a corporate system and those bin paths are not editable. I did double-check this.

Comment: I added the alternative of editing the getbuildinfo.c file, I assume you can edit that if you can compile your own Python

Answer (score 0):

I renamed svnversion (as suggested) after finding it by using 'which svnversion' and then ran 'make' again on Python3.0 and it worked.